# make exception for previous rule in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

For example if I want to add something or edit something the url will be like:

```
www.website.com/page_name/add
```

And that rule is applicable for all pages except for one page named portfolio.. for this page I want first to get a category value and than add or edit stuffs.

I tried under the first rule to put this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=portfolio&category=$1 [L]
```

To get a link like that:

```
www.website.com/portfolio/demos
```

Or

```
www.website.com/portfolio/desings
```

But always the first rule that works (consider the 2nd parameter like an action and not like an category).

Any idea for make exception for that specific page to treat what comes after like an "cat" and not like an "action"?

Comment: I don't see `porfolio/` in any of the links you want to get from the second rule.

Comment: I modified them

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(portfolio)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&category=$2 [L]` won't this work when you place this above `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&action=$2 [L]`

Comment: @IBMdig both rules are directing to the same place. The second rule you have provided has 1 parameter, not 2, so `$2` is invalid. Where should the `portfolio/` rule send the user?

Comment: i'm guessing portfolio is the page, so add brackets around that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `L` flag in HTACCESS tells Apache to ignore anything after that rule if the pattern is a match (which it is in your example).

Swap the rules around:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=???&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Also, notice that in the first rule, there is no second parameter (since there's only one pattern), so I'm not sure where you intend to send the user...

Comment: for the parameters I copied the first rule and forget to modified it lol.. But yes the problem was in the order of the 2 rules.. I thought that if i put it under the 1st will overide it but i was worng.. and now it works Thnak's a lot

Answer (score 2):

First exclude portifilio from first rule so , replace this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portfolio
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

Also in this rule :

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

you will be able match against the number only not page name , it should be like this :

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=portfolio&category=$1 [L]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^(whatever)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$ ?page=$1&category=$2 [L]
```

Comment: But then, what is the point? The second rule behaves exactly as the first one would anyway...

Comment: makes more sense to swap the 2 lines around so the desired rewrite is hit first instead of excluding pages

Comment: @BenM you are right , but the OP asked if he could exclude it to  use as he want , I expected he want to know the way to exclude it then change apply change

Comment: @Juakali92 no this line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portfolio will exclude any URI start with portfolio

Comment: i know what the line does, it just adds more logic whilst it's not required.

Comment: @Juakali92 no it is required to exclude portfolio from the next rule

Comment: if you swap the lines around, the L flag will stop at the rule it matches, so all you need to do is put `^portfolio/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$` line above `^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)$` and it will work. You don't need to exclude anything

Comment: @Juakali92 yes it is just here when the redirection is going to be query string , you are right , but the OP question is how to exclude it from first rule then either use it as it is or another way , that why i gave him safe way to manipulate with it  after that